# How to apply PHP inside HTML that is running in a if statement

Tags: php, html

I need to get this code running but i need your help. It is a PHP script with a if statement combined to a categorie. The problem is that the output isn't compleet. The php action that give back a value that needs to be apply'd on the product page in the backend off Wordpress should be  displays in the tabel after the day prijs but isn't visible.

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_single_category_slug' );

function bbloomer_single_category_slug() {

if ( has_term( 'verhuur-mini-gravers', 'product_cat' ) ) { ?>
<div class="view-right">
<h2>Verhuur prijzen</h2>
<table style="width:100%; border: 1px #000;">
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:500;">Dag prijs</td>
<td style="font-weight:500;">4 dagen prijs</td>
<td style="font-weight:500;">Week prijs</td><td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>€ <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field_17', true ) ?></td>
<td>€ <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field_18', true ) ?></td>
<td>€ <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field_19', true ) ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php; } elseif ( has_term( 'tables', 'product_cat' ) ) {
            echo 'Something else';
        }

    }?>
```

The value of the _text_field_17 should be visible with the value. Now the get_post_meta is not visible or not running.

Comment: What does your PHP error log say?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Good thing that you wrote a function to do so. You might consider indenting your codes, so that you can see the bugs before testing.

One way is to just define a string `$html` and store everything in it and at the end just return that, maybe similar to:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_single_category_slug');

function bbloomerSingleCategorySlug($post)
{
    $html = '';
    if (isset($post) && has_term('verhuur-mini-gravers', 'product_cat')) {
        $html .= '<div class="view-right">';
        $html .= '<h2>Verhuur prijzen</h2>';
        $html .= '<table style="width:100%; border: 1px #000;">';
        $html .= '<tr></tr>';
        $html .= '<tr><td style="font-weight:500;">Dag prijs</td><td style="font-weight:500;">4 dagen prijs</td><td style="font-weight:500;">Week prijs</td><td></tr>';

        $html .= '<tr><td>€ ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "_text_field_17", true) . '</td>';
        $html .= '<td>€ ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "_text_field_18", true) . '</td>';
        $html .= '<td>€ ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, "_text_field_19", true) . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr><tr>';
        $html .= '</table>';
        $html .= '</div>';
    } elseif (has_term('tables', 'product_cat')) {
        echo 'Something else';
    } else {
        echo 'Something is not right! Maybe, check the $post variable!';
    }
    echo $html;
}
```

I'm not so sure about your variables in Woocommerce, you may want to check on that. If you wish, you can pass `$post` as a variable in the function.